# How are moduli stacks used?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Can someone give me an indication or reference for a situation in which the geometry of some moduli stack is "used"? I know that intersection theory and cohomologies can be developed on algebraic stacks, and I've seen some references for computing the l-adic cohomology of the moduli stacks of vector bundles on curves over $F_p$, for example. But once these computations are done, what use are they? (Use for what? Let's say, a problem that could be introduced in a lecture to undergraduate math majors, or to non-specialists.)

It would be interesting to me if one could guarantee the existence of vector bundles or genus g with certain properties, by studying the intersection of divisors corresponding to codimension one conditions on the moduli stack.  Does this strategy work in some concrete instance? I'd appreciate a reference, or some vague description of a strategy that does work.

(In a deleted comment Mumfords Picard Groups of Moduli Problems was mentioned.)

Comment: @Hoot I think I understand why one needs to leave the category of schemes (nontrivial automorphims) , that is not really what I am asking. I'll look at your reference though, thanks.

Comment: I think I understand you somewhat better now. Mumford at least does a calculation that really seems to mean something to me.

Comment: @Hoot I am looking at that reference now and it seems really great. Thanks!

Comment: This may be a good mathoverflow question.